# Acquire/release semantics on atomic variables accessed via []-operator

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, shared-memory

Assume an array of atomic variables and a class that regulates access to that array by overloading the class' `[]`-operator to return a reference to the atomic variable at position `idx`:

```
class MyClass {
public:
    MyClass()
    {
        //initalize every array element with nullptr
        for (auto& it : array) {
            it = nullptr;
        }
    }
    std::atomic<int*>& operator[](const size_t idx)
    {
         //there is some more code here, doing basic safety checks,...
         return array[idx];
    }
private:
    std::array<std::atomic<int*>, 1000> array;

}
```

We can access elements of `array`like this:

```
MyClass foo();
int *a = foo[0];
int b = 3;
foo[1] = &b
```

Note that any access to such an element will by default be done using `memory_order_seq_cst`. To change the enforced memory order, one could do:

```
int *a = foo[0].load(memory_order_acquire);
foo[1].store(&b, memory_order_release);
```

But how can I change implementation of the `[]`-operator such that `memory_order_acquire` is used for all reads and `memory_order_release` is used for all writes? The reason why I want to do this in the definition of the `[]`-operator is that there are a lot of accesses the elements of `array` at a lot of different locations in the source and I do not want to spread the used memory ordering to all of them.

EDIT: As discussed in the comments, one could replace the `[]`-operator with a getter and setter. However, that would require all accesses to be replaced by the appropriate function; plus I am interested whether or not it is possible to do it the way I outlined above.

Comment: I would do 2 different methods for that and remove `operator []`.

Comment: @Jarod42: I thought about that too, but it would require to replace all usages of the []-operator with the getter/setter. Possible for sure, but not so nice. Plus I'm really curious if this is somehow possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use an intermediate reference object that is the result of the `operator[]`. This object then applies the load or store operation based on how the object is used in a future expression.

```
class MyClass {
    struct Ref {
        std::atomic<int *> &ref_;
        Ref (std::atomic<int *> &r) : ref_(r) {}
        operator int * () const {
            return ref_.load(std::memory_order_acquire);
        }
        int * operator = (int *ptr) const {
            ref_.store(ptr, std::memory_order_release);
            return ptr;
        }
    };
public:
    //...
    Ref operator[](const size_t idx)
    {
         //there is some more code here, doing basic safety checks,...
         return array[idx];
    }
    //...
};
```

Then, the conversion operator or the assignment operator will use the right memory order constraint:

```
MyClass foo;
int *a = foo[0];  // uses conversion operator, load(acquire)
int b = 3;
foo[1] = &b;      // uses assignment operator, store(release)
```